# How can I access Internet from private network

Tags: networking, router

My office has a network that only allow to access the Internet from some computers with specific IP and MAC address
I have a linksys router and I also know the those IP and MAC addresses and I want to use this router to access the Internet as those computers.
How can I do it?

My office do not allow staff to access the Internet from working PC because security, so we have some other PCs to search document. But this searching PC is very slow and I want to fake searching PC by my working PC to access the Internet

Comment: You can add your IP and MAC in your office's firewall and connect to the network, then you will be able access internet.

Comment: My office do not allow staff to access the Internet from working PC because security, so we have some other PCs to search document. But this searching PC is very slow and I want to fake searching PC by my working PC to access the Internet

Answer (score 0):

You would need to [spoof your MAC address](https://github.com/feross/SpoofMAC), and then set your IP address. Using 2 devices at the same time with same mac addresses in the same network will definitely cause undefined behavior.

EDIT: Or ask your IT support/whatever to add your computer to the white-list

Comment: How I do it in Window?